How do I configure 2 public IP addresses on Debian and enable NAT traversal on one?
I got 2 IP addresses from my hosting company, xx.xx.xx.109 and xx.xx.xx.110, both in the same subnet. The subnet mask is 255.255.255.192 and the gateway is xx.xx.xx.20
I have a Proxmox server and would like to keep network access between management and VMs separate. So xx.xx.xx.109 would be used by the host and xx.xx.xx.110 would be used by VM guests to access the internet.
Due to my hosting company's rules all network traffic must come from a registered MAC address, so my VMs would need a private IP range (e.g. 10.0.0.x) and make use of NAT traversal to access the internet through xx.xx.xx.110.
How do I achieve this?
